# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with external library

Tags: corda

I have created a custom jar file and tried to access the function in the java file from Flow in `corda 3.3 version`. I have added the jar file using Project `Structure>Project Settings>Libraries>Java>`. While running the code its not identifying the class path of added jar file and throwing j`ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

```
Modified the build.gradle file and added  flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
       } where the jar file is residing
```

Comment: Have you create a libs folder and put that jar into it

Comment: yes I have done and its working in a simple kotlin project but when I used it in corda example project its not working, build is happening without any issues and when I run it from IntelliJ and trying to initiate an api call its logging the error as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: I have set the jar file to wrong module. Corrected it by pointing to correct module and the issue got resolve